# Android - Is WebView localStorage stored in the app cache?

Tags: android, local-storage, storage

I am writing a hybrid app (Cordova 6.5, Angular 1.5, Ionic 1.3, HTML5) that will run on Android. This kind of app works in WebView.

My app has a few images bundled with the app and most of the data will be called via HTTP and some of it will be stored in localStorage for offline mode.

I have seen that it's possible to manually write images etc. into the app cache (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), but I am not doing this myself in my app.

I am wondering what kind of data does the Android OS store in the app cache by default. I hope this does not include the html5 localStorage.

Comment: `localStorage` does not store in app cache. but if you clear app data in settings->app you will clear them.

Comment: Can you put your comment as an answer with a source? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` does not store in app cache. but if you clear app data in settings->app you will clear them.
I just test it in android.

more info [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)